# EXCEL CONCATENATED SUMIFS are ignoring filters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

I have table with summary like that.

[image]

To achieve that summary I used formula like that:

```
CONCATENATE(SUMIFS(A2:A13;C2:C13;"=JPY");" JPY";CHAR(10);SUMIFS(A2:A13;C2:C13;"=EUR");" EUR";CHAR(10);SUMIFS(A2:A13;C2:C13;"=PLN");" PLN"; )
```

The problem is its not working with filters in column. How can I modify this formula to consider filters?

It needs to be in single cell because this sheet is created in java.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  If you mean it is including the invisible rows in the total, that is normal behavior for that function. If you need to include only visible rows in the sum, investigate the `SUBTOTAL` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://www.statology.org/excel-subtotal-sumif/) explains it fairly well.

The formula would be:

```
=CONCATENATE(SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:A13)-ROW(A2),,1)),--(C2:C13="JPY")), " JPY", CHAR(10),
             SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:A13)-ROW(A2),,1)),--(C2:C13="EUR")), " EUR", CHAR(10),
             SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:A13)-ROW(A2),,1)),--(C2:C13="PLN")), " PLN")
```

or for ease of copying in your locality:

```
=CONCATENATE(SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109;OFFSET(A2;ROW(A2:A13)-ROW(A2);;1));--(C2:C13="JPY")); " JPY"; CHAR(10);
             SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109;OFFSET(A2;ROW(A2:A13)-ROW(A2);;1));--(C2:C13="EUR")); " EUR"; CHAR(10);
             SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109;OFFSET(A2;ROW(A2:A13)-ROW(A2);;1));--(C2:C13="PLN")); " PLN")
```